# How can we prove $\int_1^\pi x \cos(\frac1{x}) dx<4$ by hand?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Is there any way we can prove this definite integral inequality by hand:
$$
\int_{1}^{\pi}x\cos\left(1 \over x\right)\,{\rm d}x < 4
$$ 
I don't where to start even, please help. That
$\displaystyle\cos\left(1 \over x\right)\ \leq\ 1$ doesn't seem to help because $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\pi}x\,{\rm d}x\ >\ 4$.

Comment: In theory it can be done by hand after a very long calculation using right hand end point method, for example $$\displaystyle\int_1^\pi x \cos(\dfrac{1}{x}) dx<\dfrac{1}{25} (-1+\pi) \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{25} (1+\dfrac{1}{25} (-1+\pi) n) \cos(\dfrac{1}{(1+\dfrac{1}{25} (-1+\pi) n)})<3.98$$ But I am sure that this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @zuriel. Would you do that by hand as the OP asks ? Not me (I am too lazy). Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, surely I will not do that literally. But in theory if anyone is willing to spend long enough he can do it. Also I am aware what this is not what the OP asks.

Comment: @zuriel. In such a case, there is an analytical solution to the problem and it is not complex at all. Cheers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}
∫_1^π x \cos \left(\frac1{x}\right)dx&=∫_{1}^{1/π}\frac{\cos {u}}{u}\left(-\frac{du}{u^2}\right)\\
&=∫_{1/π}^{1}\frac{\cos {u}}{u^3}du\\
&\leq∫_{1/π}^{1}\frac{1-\frac12u^2+\frac{1}{24}u^4}{u^3}du
\end{align}$$

Comment: I was also thinking about using the taylor expansion of cos. can you do it? the taylor is taken in $x=0$ and you are integrating in $[\frac{1}{\pi}, 1]$where am i false?

Comment: @Ale, you may not want to use the taylor expansion of $\cos(1/x)$ directly.

Comment: @zuriel this is clear, and this is the reason why one makes the substitution $u = \frac{1}{x}$, but can you use the taylor expansion of cos in the interval $[\frac{1}{\pi}, 1]$? My question comes from the fact that $cos(x) = 1-\frac{u^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$ is taken in $x = 0$

Comment: $\frac{\pi^2-1}{2}-\frac{\log(\pi)}{2}+\frac{\pi^2-1}{48\pi^2} \doteq3.88115973296076$ which works (+1)

Answer (score 6):

First of all,

$$∫_{x=1}^π x\cos \frac{1}{x}dx=∫_{t=1}^\frac{1}{π} \frac{1}{t}*\cos \left(t\right)*\frac{-1}{t^2}dt$$

Next we have $$\cos \left(t\right) < 1 - \frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24}$$

Hence the given integral is smaller than

$$∫_{t=1}^\frac{1}{π} \frac{-1}{t^3}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24}\right)dt=3.8811597.. $$

Answer (score 3):

The integral of x dx is only a little bit greater than 4. 
For x < pi, cos (1/x) is not just ≤ 1. It's ≤ cos (1/pi). For x ≤ 2, it's ≤ cos (1/2).

Comment: $\cos(1/\pi)\frac{\pi^2-4}{2}+\cos(1/2)\frac{4-1}{2}\doteq4.10374835433948$ which is still greater than $4$.

Comment: A little bit ? $\frac{1}{2} \left(\pi ^2-1\right) \simeq 4.4348$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think that statement can be ignored. Isn't it? But of course, cos(1/pi) = 0.949 and doesn't much help. :(

Comment: @tpb261. I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

At the interval from $1/\pi$ to $1$ function $\cos(x)$ can be bounded from above by tangent line.
$$
\cos(x) \leq (\cos'(x)|_{\pi/6} ) (x - \frac{\pi}{6}) + \cos(\pi/6) = -\frac{1}{2} (x - \frac{\pi}{6}) + \cos(\frac{\pi}{6}).
$$
So the integral
$$
\int_1^\pi x \; \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq  \int_1^\pi  x \left( -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\pi}{6}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)
$$
the last integral can be easily computed by hand and equals $\approx 3.93...$

Comment: Where does $\pi/6$ come from?

Comment: @vonbrand It's just a convenient point that lies inside interval $(1/\pi, 1)$. cos(x) is convex in that interval so we can be sure that tangent line is indeed above cos(x). We can choose another point, but you'll then need to calculate cos at that point.